# How to read hadoop map file using python?

Tags: python, hadoop

I have map file that is block compressed using DefaultCodec. The map file is created by java application like this:

```
MapFile.Writer writer =
            new MapFile.Writer(conf, path,
                    MapFile.Writer.keyClass(IntWritable.class),
                    MapFile.Writer.valueClass(BytesWritable.class),
                    MapFile.Writer.compression(SequenceFile.CompressionType.BLOCK, new DefaultCodec()));
```

This file is stored in hdfs and I need to read some key,values from it in another application using python. I can't find any library that can do that. Do you have any suggestion and example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Spark which has a function called textFile() which can read files from HDFS and turn them into RDDs for further processing using other Spark libraries.

Here's the documentation : [Pyspark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html)

Comment: Can you provide an example with reading value based on a key from a MapFile? I can't find it in the docs. It looks like the docs doesn't apply to MapFile.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reader as follow:

```
path = '/hdfs/path/to/file'
key = LongWritable()
value = LongWritable()
reader = MapFile.Reader(path)
while reader.next(key, value):
        print key, value
```

Check out these [hadoop.io.MapFile Python examples](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40h%40a%40Hadoop-HEAD%40python-hadoop%40examples%40MapFileTest.py/31/hadoop.io.MapFile.Reader/python)

And [available methods in MapFile.py](https://github.com/matteobertozzi/Hadoop/blob/master/python-hadoop/hadoop/io/MapFile.py)

Comment: I tried to use it and I can't read it. I got this error: 
    No such file or directory: 'hdfs://myserver:9000/tmp/mapfile/data'. 
I looked at code and it is using: 
   os.path.join(dirname, DATA_FILE_NAME)
It looks like it can only read local map file. Not the one in hdfs. Are you able to read it from hdfs? Can you provide more help?